# Force Visual Styles

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that I want to use Visual Styles and I have Application.EnableVisualStyles(); in the program but I have some customers that use windows XP with classic windows theme so the visual styles dont show on those machines. Is there any way to "Force" visual styles regardless of what the windows theme is?

Comment: Try third party skinning like DevExpress.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? They chose classic design for a reason...

Comment: Technically we changed it to classic for them for performance reasons, but many of our users prefer the visual style version of the application over the classic style. And frankly, changing all the computers themes would be way too time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is detected by RenderWithVisualStyles property - and this in turn is controlled by various factors listed - see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.renderwithvisualstyles.aspx).

If you want to force your styles, you may consider [overriding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830033) some of the theming behaviour.

Comment: I tried the code in that link and it didn't seem to work for my application. I guess I just need a way to override the VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser.